# Automatically resizing columns to fit their captions not cell content only

Tags: model-view-controller, devexpress

I have gridview where I have columns with same content lenght but different lenght of captions and gridview has `BestFit` parametr for resizing set by default only for content. So in my cases many columns look like this:

```
|  Price  |  Price  w| (Price with VAT should be)

|   123459|    213544|
```

And I have to resize all those columns manually so is there some option to set resizing automatically for caption and not only for content?

Comment: WinForms, WPF, ASP.NET or HTML5/JS?

Comment: ASP. NET MVC, view is made with devexpress components